# Impulse Response of a dummy Variable

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I am writing a paper about electoral periods and its effect in the exchange rate. I estimated a VAR model where the electoral period dummy its included in the var. I am trying to measure the impulse response effect of that dummy over all the model variables, and I am getting good results, but I dont think its a statistically correct method, since:

1. The electoral period variable should be exogenous (i tried doing an irf following some documentation but couldnt manage to get a result to compare with the method stated here.
2. How can i be sure that the impulse measured in the irf function means electoral period dummy going 0 -> 1 (since irf its unit increase)
3. I am not sure about how correct is including a dummy inside a VAR model as a variable since its interaction its not the same as "normal" variables
4. Finally, I read some documentation online stating that the irf plot has to converge to zero in all cases if using a VAR model, but I am not sure thats right since I tested for model stability with cumsum test and it looks pretty stable.

Any suggestions or clarifications?